# Could not find plugin Stormpath SDK JsonNetSerializer

Tags: .net, oauth, nuget, stormpath

I'm facing an issue with StormPath when trying to get my application. I am developing in .NET Framework.

I can clearly see in my NuGet packages that Stormpath.SDK.JsonNetSerializer has been installed when I installed Stormpath.SDK.

However, I'm getting this error:

> Error while loading the default serializer. See the inner exception for details.
>   
> Inner Exception: Could not find plugin 'Stormpath.SDK.JsonNetSerializer'. Try specifying the plugins manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the package. Sorry about the confusion; this is a problem that happens in some environments. In the next major version, I'm going to refactor the internals to remove this error mode.

In the mean time, try specifying the plugins manually to get around it:

```
var client = Clients.Builder()
    .SetHttpClient(HttpClients.Create().RestSharpClient())
    .SetSerializer(Serializers.Create().JsonNetSerializer())
    .Build();
```

Comment: Thank you, only difference I have made to your suggestion is instead of SystemNetHttpClient, I have used RestSharpClient(). Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Gotcha, I edited my answer. I was trying to guess your environment. :) Let me know if you have any more questions about the library!

Comment: Hi Nate, what is the best practice on making this only executed once only i.e. running on at start up. So once it created client builder instance, each request made it can continue to do its operation (Add user, remove user and etc) ? i can create singleton instance but thinking on start up it should execute the code to create instance

Comment: @helloworld You should create the client once and then store it as a `static` variable, or better yet use an IOC container like Ninject or StructureMap. If you are using the [ASP.NET plugin](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/), this is done automatically for you.

Comment: Thank you. For future inquiry with StormPath how can I contact you or team for development side?

Comment: You can always email support@stormpath.com for any questions, or join the Stormpath [Slack channel](https://talkstormpath.shipit.xyz/). And we answer questions here on StackOverflow pretty regularly!